# Write a program that will receive numbers from the user until the user will enter 0 or a negative number

Tags: c++

I need to write a program that will receive numbers from the user until the user will enter 0 or a negative number and that the program will print out the biggest number.
**so my problem is**: if I put the first number as the biggest one, the program is not receiving it for some reason 
any ideas why? 
click here for the image of the code >>

[image: Here is my code so far]

Comment: What if the user enters a non-number like `x`?

Comment: Idk, my program just terminates itself, its only my second lesson in cpp so I dont know

Comment: Just look at the code, and pretend that you're the computer. What do you do first, what do you do next, etc. This really is a simple problem in control flow, and you have to learn to read this sort of code for yourself.

Comment: You want to use a `do`-`while` loop.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar - that's one possibility, but not the only one.

Comment: @PeteBecker : the OP clearly doesn't care about having to choose from multiple possibilities, and I believe that mine is a one that guarantees him the least work.

Comment: You might want to step thru the code with a debugger. Sometimes that makes things much more clear.

Comment: @Logicrat - yes, that's good advice, although this one is simple enough that the debugger in the head ought to be the first resort. <g>

Comment: It would be better if you could add the code and the output directly to your question insted of linking an image.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, that is a good point, and I agree. Using the development system's debugger should not be the first technique to employ.

Comment: This question is of zero value to the community. The code isn't even text-indexable. Stack Overflow is _not_ a personal helpdesk!

Answer (score 1):

In your code the first `num` collected is overwritten by the `cin` in the loop, so it is not considered when comparing to `biggest`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are redefining num before you are even reading it.

You should change your program flow to check whenever num is bigger than num, before reading it again.

Answer (score 0):

**I would suggest debugging the code on your own before proceeding. :)**  
The problem in your code is with the line highlighted in red below:

[image]

What is happening is, when the underlined code **cin>>num** is executed, num contains the value 999.  Within the while loop, when you again input the value of num (shown by an asterik), this value is overwritten with the new value (i.e., 123).  Hence when the max value is output, the answer displayed is 123, which is indeed correct.  If you want to rectify this error, please remove the **cin>>num**
that is underlined.